# Cannot connect to EC2 instance in one line of command

Tags: amazon-ec2, unix

I am trying one line setup command.

`ssh -i "$(cat kushal.pub)" kushal@ec2-18-216-221-164.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

Just to break this real quick I'm reading my .pub file and then while connecting, I am creating a .ssh folder with permissions 700 and inside that folder a file with permission 600 appending my public key into it.

But I get permission Denied error(public key).

Now, I did have connected instance manually by copying the public key generated by `ssh-keygen -y` and through a series of commands. But I don't what's going wrong with the same commands but in one line. How can I work it out?

And to overflow my question a bit more. Is there any difference if I use `ssh-keygen -y` compared to `ssh-keygen - t rsa` for generating public key files?

Just making sure if this won't make any difference to the error output

Comment: `ssh -i` expects the filename of the identity file, not the content. This should be `ssh -i kushal.pub`.

Comment: Ok. I did this cause I needed to pipe the output on the server. The output in this case being content yeah...Actually I need to place my output of cat command to `ssh -i` command. So yes, I am doing something wrong.